# Thru-Hole Works, SMD Does not

Tags: audio, analog, surface-mount

I have been working on migrating a through-hole circuit design that works to a surface mount version.

It is a preamp designed by an engineer named Ritter. Here is his schematic:

www.ciphersbyritter.com/RADELECT/PREJFET/JFETPRE.HTM

We have made a through-hole circuit board that works perfectly, but when we migrate the design to use SMT parts the DC output voltage becomes much higher. This is an issue as we are trying to impedance match the preamp so it will be accepted as a mic into smartphones. (FYI the preamp still sounds great)

We have throughly compared the thru hole and smd boards and cannot see any significant difference except size, the smd board is much smaller, and that we are using different components (smtd versions of the thru-hole parts).

The Electrical Engineer on our team says that perhaps it is radiation occurring from the traces being too close to each other. Could this be a factor? Is there any thing else I could be testing for to find the difference between my seemingly schematically identical boards?

**UPDATE**

We have built two through-hole versions to see if they consistently output with the same DC bias of around 1.2V. Two of the three boards have a 1.2V output bias. The third has an output bias of 3V.

We then removed the transistors from the board putting out 3V and setup a breadboard system so we could substitute in different transistors. We tried about 3 different sets of transistors, and none of them affected the boards DC bias. We didn't substitute resistors, but we tested all of their resistance to see if they were any different from the working board and they were not.

We are now collecting as much data as we can from board to board. We have made a diagram of the lines we are testing between. We are testing the voltage and resistance between most traces of the board and comparing the results from Board A (1.2V bias) and Board B (3.0V bias).

Here is a link to the spreadsheet where are collecting our data:
http://tinyurl.com/zyctqm7

Schematic:
[image]

Comment: "DC output voltage becomes much higher", can you post measured differences?

Comment: First, double check all your part selections, from the data sheets or direct measurement.  If that doesn't solve it, make up a bunch of test coupons that let you use the SMD parts in a through-hole or breadboard circuit.  Figure out which is behaving differently.  Or take time to understand the circuit and realize from that which component must be off to yield the observed result.

Comment: Draw the new circuit naming the exact parts you used as direct equivalents.

Comment: Not sure I like the comment that the PNP's load resistor is missing. That reduces the current through it. We should not see more gain as a result because of the overall R4/R5 30dB negative feedback. Put that resistor in then compare circuits. Does 2N5484 have an exact SMD equivalent, including Vgsth spec, and a similar sub-threshold curve, which is where this description suggests the FET is running.

Comment: It's a pretty naive circuit. He talks about setting the output voltage by selecting FETs, presumably your SMD parts are from a different wafer than your through hole ones. You could test this by fitting a TH FET to an SMD board and vice versa. Increasing R2 will probably reduce the output voltage a bit.

Comment: This is probably due to V_th variation in the FETs you're using, JFETs are notorious for having very poor consistency in V_th within a single batch. Look at some JFET datasheets and you'll see what I mean, V_th values vary over a large range, I mean the 2N5484 has a V_gs off (V_th) range of 0.3>3.0 V (1:10). Good luck!

Comment: I had a board with similar problems, it turned out somebody didn't translate a bom correctly and we had a different value for a filter cap. If you think it's EMI then do a test and shield it as best you can, if the offset doesn't go away then its probably something else.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this is all very helpful.

It is worth noting two things:

1. I made breakout boards of the SMTs and put them into a breadboard. With *thru-hole* parts the **output voltage was 1.2V**. With all *SMD* parts, the **output voltage jumped up to 4V**. I have a chart of the change in output voltage when substituting each individual component which I can post if that may help.

2. I attached all thru-hole parts to the board I received from OSH-Park to see if it would function like the breadboard (1.2V output voltage). The output voltage is not the same. Board sounds good though

Comment: It's not radiation, not in an audio environment. What it could be is a bad design to begin with, in that the variations in part tolerances have not been considered (I see this a lot in audio - 5% per resistor can add up). Have you ever tried running a Monte-Carlo simulation on it to see what the variations could be?

Comment: @BrianDrummond What would you say is naive about the circuit? 
Could you suggest any other preamp circuits that may work better?

Comment: @DanielMcNamara Can you please add a schematic? I looked at your board layout and too much information was too hard to read.

Comment: @Tyler Ok, added

Comment: Have you put an oscilloscope on the output?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes, both boards put a signal that is that same size from peak to peak, but the one boards output is biased at 1V and the other is biased at 3V

Comment: The difference in the offset is primarily going to be due to the JFET input stage, the BJT stages that follow can't change the output biasing. The input stage can be replaced with an emitter follower (high input impedance) + common collector amplifier (gain).